# Forward declare a function/task

Tags: function, task, verilog, system-verilog, forward-declaration

I browsed through the internet, and I've only saw people doing forward declarations on class using the `typedef` keyword. But, I was wondering how'd I do that with functions/tasks?

I wanted to put the main function above the definitions of other functions/tasks to ease the reader when one is previewing it. In C++, forward declaration for a function looks something like this:

```
//forward declaration of sub2
int sub2(int A, int B);

int main(){
    cout << "Difference: " << sub2(25, 10);
    return 0;
}

int sub2(int A, int B) //Defining sub2 here{
    return A - B;
}
```

For SystemVerilog, will it be something like this?

```
function somefunction();

virtual task body();
    somefunction();
endtask: body

function somefunction();
    // do something here.
endfunction: somefunction
```

Should I use `typedef` for forward declarations with functions/tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions and tasks do not need to be declared before use as long as they have a set of trailing parenthesis `()` which may also include required arguments. They use search rules similar to hierarchical references. See section *23.8.1 Task and function name resolution* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration order doesn't matter, like in C. You can call `somefunction` in `body` before declaring it.

You don't need to do any kind of declarations.